# How should I use Enums in Openjpa entities?

Tags: java, openjpa

I'm trying to use an enum field in an openjpa entiy. Everything works fine unitl I try to enhance my entities which breaks with a ClassNotFound exception for the Enum type. I'm using the openjpa maven plugin to enhance the entities and the enum is declared public and is on the classpath. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Does the error state which class is missing?

Comment: (Sorry, it looks like you answered that.)  Are there any wrapped exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem.

You need to include the missing class in the classpath you use when you define the task.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be a bug -- see this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1121).